# How to deploy a React project using Webpack on Server side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, web-deployment, webpack-dev-server

I have come across many articles pertaining to creating a client side project using webpack and react. But how to deploy the same client side project on to a server to be hosted on Linux. Which technology has to be used on linux server to that i can host my react project ?

If webpack is used on client side and the project is built on client side, how to use the same bundle.js file on to a linux server so that it can run as a server?

If Node.js is a good option , how to do it?

Comment: Given you've built the HTML/CSS/JS/etc. outputs from the client app, literally any webserver can be used to serve them - for example Apache or Nginx. You _could_ use Node, with e.g. Express.

Comment: Can you please guide how to deploy it using express on a linux box?

Comment: I'd suggest researching that - reading https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/ would be a good start, even if you're not using CRA you have similar needs.

Comment: Using Node.js as a server a bad idea?